# Can I use use simplification (rule of inference) inside a negated expression?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

The question gives these premises and asks for the conclusion.

- $P \land Q$
- $P \implies \neg(Q\land R)$
- $S\implies R$

Also there are choices: a) $\neg S$ b)$\neg P$ c) $\neg R$ d) None of the above

Here is my approach:

1. $P \land Q$, premise
2. $P$, simplification from 1
3. $P \implies \neg (Q\land R)$, premise
4. $\neg (Q \land R)$, modus ponens from 2 and 3
5. $\neg Q \lor \neg R$, De Morgan's law applied on 4
6. $S \implies R$, premise
7. $\neg S \lor R$, logically equivalent to 6
8. $\neg Q \lor \neg S$, resolution from 5 and 7

At this point, should I choose none of the above? or if I continue as

9. $\neg (Q\land S)$, from 8
10. $\neg (S)$, simplification of $(Q \land S)$ in step 9

My question: Is step 10 true? can I do simplification inside the negation and then apply the negation? and in this case the answer would be (a).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot infer $\neg S$ from $\neg (Q \land S)$!

Imagine that $Q$ is False but $S$ is True. Then $\neg (Q \land S)$, which says that $Q$ and $S$ are not both True would be true itself: indeed it is not the case that both $Q$ and $S$ are True.  However, $\neg S$ would be False.  So, inferring $\neg S$ from $\neg (Q \land S)$ is an invalid inference.

In general, when you try to apply Simplification to an embedded statement, sometimes the result does validly follow from the original statement, but sometimes it does not.  For example, $\neg \neg S$  *does* follow from $\neg \neg (Q \land S)$. Inferring $P \to S$ from $P \to (Q \land S)$ is also valid ... but inferring $S \to P$ from $(Q \land S) \to P$ is *not*.

Now, you can come up with some rule that lays out the conditions under which you can apply something like Simplification to an embedded conjunction, but it is not straightforward, and it is easy to make mistakes. So, much better is to simply say that inference rules can never be applied to embedded statements, and that is exactly what almost every logical inference system does.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question I got it. However, I've seen another solution that concludes $\neg S$. Doesn't that make a contradiction between this answer and my answer?

Comment: @AsmaaMesbah  It is true that $\neg S$ does follow from the *original* premises of this argument. But the specific inference from $\neg (Q \land S)$ to $\neg S$ is not valid. So all that that means is that the *latter* way of trying to get to $\neg S$ does not work ... but that there is a *different* way to get to $\neg S$.  So no, what I said does not contradict with the fact that you can infer $\neg S$ from the original premises.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. I finally got it and found a way to get to $\neg S$.

Comment: @AsmaaMesbah Cool!  Glad I could help :)